# QnAMaker getting different results using GetAnswersRawAsync vs GetAnswersAsync in Botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

When running a multi-turn conversation I am getting different results between GetAnswersRawAsync and GetAnswersAsync.  GetAnswersRawAsync returns zero results about every 5th call where as GetAnswersAsync seems to always return.  Is this a bug?  What is the difference between the two?  The documentation for both seems the same.

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CallGenerateAnswerAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var qnaMakerOptions = new QnAMakerOptions
        {
            ScoreThreshold = DefaultThreshold,
            Top = DefaultTopN,
            Context = new QnARequestContext(),
            QnAId = 0
        };

        var dialogOptions = GetDialogOptionsValue(stepContext);

        // Getting options
        if (dialogOptions.ContainsKey(QnAOptions))
        {
            qnaMakerOptions = dialogOptions[QnAOptions] as QnAMakerOptions;
            qnaMakerOptions.ScoreThreshold = qnaMakerOptions?.ScoreThreshold ?? DefaultThreshold;
            qnaMakerOptions.Top = DefaultTopN;
        }

        // Storing the context info
        stepContext.Values[CurrentQuery] = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text;

        // -Check if previous context is present, if yes then put it with the query
        // -Check for id if query is present in reverse index.
        if (!dialogOptions.ContainsKey(QnAContextData))
        {
            dialogOptions[QnAContextData] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }
        else
        {
            var previousContextData = dialogOptions[QnAContextData] as Dictionary<string, int>;
            if (dialogOptions[PreviousQnAId] != null)
            {
                var previousQnAId = Convert.ToInt32(dialogOptions[PreviousQnAId]);

                if (previousQnAId > 0)
                {
                    qnaMakerOptions.Context = new QnARequestContext
                    {
                        PreviousQnAId = previousQnAId
                    };

                    qnaMakerOptions.QnAId = 0;
                    if (previousContextData.TryGetValue(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text.ToLower(), out var currentQnAId))
                    {
                        qnaMakerOptions.QnAId = currentQnAId;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var svc = _services.QnAMakerService;

        // Does not return a result
        var response = await svc.GetAnswersRawAsync(stepContext.Context, qnaMakerOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Returns a result
        var response2 = await svc.GetAnswersAsync(stepContext.Context, qnaMakerOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);

// Additional code removed for simplification   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the 2 is that **one returns the *entire* QnA Maker result** whereas the **other only returns the *`Answers`* property** of the whole result.

---

### `GetAnswersAsync()` - returns `QueryResult.Answer`

`GetAnswersAsync(TurnContext, QnAMakerOptions)` eventually calls the following `GetAnswersAsync` overload

```cs
        public async Task<QueryResult[]> GetAnswersAsync(
                                        ITurnContext turnContext,
                                        QnAMakerOptions options,
                                        Dictionary<string, string> telemetryProperties,
                                        Dictionary<string, double> telemetryMetrics = null)
        {
            var result = await GetAnswersRawAsync(turnContext, options, telemetryProperties, telemetryMetrics).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result.Answers;
        }
```

Notice how it just calls `GetAnswersRawAsync` and from those results, it only returns its answer.

#### vs.

### `GetAnswersRawAsync()` - returns entire `QueryResult`

```cs
        public async Task<QueryResults> GetAnswersRawAsync(
                                        ITurnContext turnContext,
                                        QnAMakerOptions options,
                                        Dictionary<string, string> telemetryProperties = null,
                                        Dictionary<string, double> telemetryMetrics = null)
        {
            if (turnContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(turnContext));
            }

            if (turnContext.Activity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The {nameof(turnContext.Activity)} property for {nameof(turnContext)} can't be null.", nameof(turnContext));
            }

            var messageActivity = turnContext.Activity.AsMessageActivity();
            if (messageActivity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Activity type is not a message");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Null or empty text");
            }

            var result = await this._generateAnswerHelper.GetAnswersRawAsync(turnContext, messageActivity, options).ConfigureAwait(false);

            await OnQnaResultsAsync(result.Answers, turnContext, telemetryProperties, telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
        }
```

You can see the source code in the botbuidler-dotnet repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA/QnAMaker.cs).